# Unable to create instance from base class in lua using metatable

Tags: class, oop, lua, lua-table

I am currently working on Defold project and need to build a class in lua.
This is my base class

```
local class = {}
class.__index = class
class.value = nil
function class.create()
    local o ={}
    setmetatable(o, class)
    return o
end
function class:printOut()
    print(class.value)
end
function class:setValue(value)
    class.value = value
end
return class
```

This is my usage in main script

```
local mclass = require "main.mclass"
local B
local C

function init(self)
    msg.post(".", "acquire_input_focus")
    msg.post("@render:", "use_fixed_fit_projection", { near = -1, far = 1 })
    B = mclass.create()
    C = mclass.create()
end

function on_input(self, action_id, action)
    if action_id == hash("touch") and action.pressed then
        B:setValue(10)
        print(B.value)
        B:setValue(12)
        print(C.value)
        --print(B.value)
    end
end
```

I suppose to create instance from base class for each B and C. But seem both of them point to a same base class. As I changed value by using B then value in C also got changed.
Did I miss something here. Or my setup for class is wrong.
Thanks for help guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mclass file, `class` always refers to the same table. That's the table that you modify/access in `printOut` and `setValue`.

By using colon notation, both of those functions have an implicit `self` parameter. Use that instead of `class` (e.g. `print(self.value)` and `self.value = value`).

Comment: I changed my mClass local class = {}
class.__index = class
function class.create()
    local o ={}
    setmetatable(o, class)
    return o
end
function class:printOut()
    print(self.value)
end
function class:setValue(value)
    self.value = value
end
return class

Answer (score 0):

I changed my mClass and it work well.

```
local class = {}
class.__index = class
function class.create()
    local o ={}
    setmetatable(o, class)
    return o
end
function class:printOut()
    print(self.value)
end
function class:setValue(value)
    self.value = value
end
return class
```

But I wonder how I should put properties in this class.
Like I have many properties in this class
self.value1
self.value2
..
Where should I put these properties

Comment: Put them in `class.create`, when you create the object: `local o = {value1=value1, value2=value2}`.

Comment: Is this look like this: local o = {
        self.mType = nil,
        self.mOrderID = nil,
        self.mAnimID = nil}
    setmetatable(o, class)
    return o.   It seems not work for me

Comment: Short answer: If all properties start out as `nil`, you don't have to initialize them at all. To straighten out your understanding, you'll need to read up on [table constructors](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) and [colon syntax](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11) (scroll down to find it).

Comment: Thats great. I'll dig in these link. Thanks for help @luther